# Slurm - Host node allocation?

Tags: slurm

When I submit by `SBATCH` job to our `HPC`, I believe slurm allocates nodes based on resources, and in my case, the Host is always spawned on **Node 0** which is set as being the 1st in an alphabetical sort of the `node/machine` names. This is causing problems because (sometimes) this Host node may only have 1 core running, (and thus a small amountof memory) meaning it is unable to write large results/data files I need.

Is there any way to set the host node manually, given the resources slurm allocates in my `nodefile`?

I could fix this with -`mincpus` but I only need >1 cpu for this one purpose. Other solutions increasing `--mem-per-cpu` or just `--mem` also just add more resources to the job and delay it from starting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--nodelist` parameter to set specific nodes that should be used:

```sh
sbatch --nodelist=<NODE-NAME> script.sh
```

Or even `--exclude` the ones you do not want to use (e.g. node 0):

```sh
sbatch --exclude=node0 script.sh
```

The [official documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) provides more information on both options.